# CSS Внутренняя и внешняя тень текста одновременно

Tags: html, css

Как я могу добиться одновременно внутренней и внешней тени текста?
Моя неудачная попытка (смог сделать только внутреннюю, внешняя не получается):

```
.text {
  font-family: RockwellExtraBold;
  text-shadow: inset -2px -5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 5px black;
    }
```

На картинке показано как должно быть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте сделать с помощью box-shadow

Comment: @Lisenok, и каким же это образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по картинке, у вас внешняя тень должна быть с четырех сторон, а в коде у вас только размытие прописано (0 0 5px black - это скорее "размытие", потому что третий параметр - как раз указывает размытие).
Посмотрите примеры тут (особенно, Border around text):
**https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_shadows.asp**

text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;

И очень удивительно, что у вас вообще работает код:
text-shadow: **inset** -2px -5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 5px black;

Насколько мне известно, inset можно добавить к border-style либо box-shadow, но никак не к текстовой тени.